# iphone app SQLite Database populate failure

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I just started learning `SQLite` interfacing with the iPhone app and I am stuck not with an error, but I am unable to insert values into a DB using the following code.

I couldnt figure out where the error creeped in here, To see an insert I have NSlogged a string to show up in debugger but the code isnt reaching till there, could you kindly help me out with this one.

I tried looking at other posts but I couldnt get much out of them, I see that my syntax and statements are correct and after seeing a particular post on SO, I realized I did a mistake at somepart and then corrected it.

But still its not working. I am working on a university owned system and I am not able to access the mac disk files whether to see my db is getting populated or even created..is there something with setting up the privileges for creating db. (i really suspect that), if so then how can i create a db elsewhere in the file system for access or is there anything wrong  in the below code, if you need any other files kindly do comment so that I can put them up here...

**vc.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
NSMutableArray *arrayOfPerson;
sqlite3 *personDB;
NSString *dbPathString;

}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
arrayOfPerson = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[[self myTableView]setDelegate:self];
[[self myTableView]setDataSource:self];
[self createOrOpenDB];
}

-(void)createOrOpenDB{

NSArray *path=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docPath=[path objectAtIndex:0];

dbPathString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"persons.db"];

char *error;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPathString]) {

    const char *dbPath=[dbPathString UTF8String];

    //creating DB
    if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &personDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sql_stmt="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSONS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT,AGE INTEGER";
        sqlite3_exec(personDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error);
        NSLog(@"Created !");
        sqlite3_close(personDB);
    }

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (IBAction)addPersonButton:(id)sender {
char *error;
if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &personDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString *insertStmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO PERSONS(NAME,AGE) VALUES         ('%s','%d')",[self.nameField.text UTF8String],[self.ageField.text intValue]];
    const char *insert_stmt = [insertStmt UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_exec(personDB, insert_stmt, NULL
                     , NULL, &error)==SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Person Added");

        Person *person = [[Person alloc]init];

        [person setName:self.nameField.text];
        [person setAge:[self.ageField.text intValue]];

        [arrayOfPerson addObject:person];


    }

    sqlite3_close(personDB);
}

}

- (IBAction)displayPersonButton:(id)sender {
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if(sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &personDB)==SQLITE_OK){
    [arrayOfPerson removeAllObjects];
    NSString *querySql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT *FROM PERSONS"];
    const char *query_sql=[querySql UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_prepare(personDB, query_sql, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
        while(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW){
            NSString *name=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,1)];
            NSString *ageString=[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];//used sqlite3_column_int here before ! Mistake
            Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];

            [person setName:name];

            [person setAge:[ageString intValue]];
            [arrayOfPerson addObject:person];

        }
    }
}
[[self myTableView] reloadData];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
[[self ageField]resignFirstResponder ];
[[self nameField]resignFirstResponder];}
- (IBAction)deletePersonButton:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

**vc.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"
#import "Person.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *ageField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
- (IBAction)addPersonButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)displayPersonButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)deletePersonButton:(id)sender;
@end
```

Did any error creep in between, I checked it to my best, but couldnt find any syntactically

Comment: OK firstly, why doesn't your view controller inherit from `UIViewController`?

Comment: it does..I believe its the default framework included...kindly correct me if my explanation is wrong..

Comment: @trojanfoe: could this be because I dont have privilege on this system to create a db..i mean write to disk...if this is so how can I set the location to create the db at some other place..is there any setting that I can change on Xcode...

Comment: When you say "the system" you are talking about the iPhone Simulator right?  If so, then permission isn't the issue I don't think - you look to be creating the database in the right place.

Comment: yes.., precisely..sorry if i confused you on that part, as I have mentioned, I am unable to access or see any file under the mac filesystem, the only place I can access are the desktop and the network file system...so I thought on those lines, I might not be able to create a DB through the source here...just doubting that

Comment: If you are logged into a normal user account on a mac then you do have access to the files of the iPhone Simulator.  They are in a hidden folder `~/Library`.  Search for SO questions related to unhiding this folder and finding the iPhone Simulator files.  You can also use `Terminal.app` to access the database using the `sqlite3` command line utility.

Comment: @Why-K-Rum Just a Thought - Why don't you use [FMDB framework](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) for all you database operations, its simple to use and is very clean.

Comment: @icodebuster: yes, I will try implementing that, thanks for the suggesting..will try that out next...but I need to figure this basic one out...

Comment: @trojanfoe: I tried as you said...the database is not getting created ...its only showing up a main database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket on your CREATE TABLE.

```
const char *sql_stmt="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSONS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT,AGE INTEGER";
```

You also don't need to wrap your integer parameter in single quotes either on this statement:

```
NSString *insertStmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO PERSONS(NAME,AGE) VALUES         ('%s','%d')",[self.nameField.text UTF8String],[self.ageField.text intValue]];
```

Try adding this code after the body of your insertion attempt to see if sqlite will give more information as to the possible error.

```
if (sqlite3_exec(personDB, insert_stmt, NULL
                 , NULL, &error)==SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Person Added");

    Person *person = [[Person alloc]init];

    [person setName:self.nameField.text];
    [person setAge:[self.ageField.text intValue]];

    [arrayOfPerson addObject:person];


}
else     // Add this in the hope it will shed more light on the problem.
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(personDB));
}
```

Just noticed too that you have a couple of issues in your - (IBAction)displayPersonButton: method.

First, you have no space between *FROM. And ideally you should name the columns you want to select rather than using *.

Second, you have no sqlite3_finalize(statement).

Third, you open the database on entry to the method but don't close it again before exit.

Comment: Have you examined the contents of char *error to see what error sqlite is reporting after you try to execute the statement?

Comment: I've added a few more observations to my answer. Hope this helps.